# Put Border in Material UI in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do you put a border only if elevation is 0 in Material-UI in React?
This code below puts a border on all card of course.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCard: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          border: `1px solid green`,
          position: "relative",
          zIndex: 0,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a specific elevation you will notice that your css class has a specific style for it. For example when you use

```
<Card elevation={4}>
```

you get a class like this `.MuiPaper-elevation4`

If you use `elevation={0}` the `Card` component will get the default class `MuiPaper-elevation0`. So you can target this class to add  the border you want and only those Card components will be affected.

Add this to your theme (remove the border from the `MuiCard` theme override)

```
MuiCard: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      // border: `1px solid green`,
      position: "relative",
      zIndex: 0,
    },
  },
},
MuiPaper: {
  styleOverrides: {
    elevation0: {
      border: '1px solid green'
    },
  },
},
```

`Then by using <Card elevation={0}>` only for that case you will have a border (this is a tested solution)

Here is the url that can help you with all the classes you can override in your theme https://mui.com/material-ui/api/paper/

Comment: Thats not what I meant. I want to put the border: `1px solid green` in the global theme if elevation is 0

Comment: Initially i gave a more generic solution, I have updated my answer to solve your issue for exactly what you want. Let me know if it helps. Thanks

Comment: This actually conflicts with the MuiAlert since the border applies also there which I dont want

Comment: Then you have two options. One, is to remove the border in your theme for the `MuiAlert` component and the second which I would strongly suggest you to do in that case, is to create a styled component for your `Card`